# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception in ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I have created an app called `phone`(ionic v-4). I have tried to implement `Phone authentication` i,e `OTP verification` using **firebase** by following this [article](https://medium.com/@gbrigens/ionic-3-phone-authentication-with-firebase-dbed967e95ef)   in the medium.

Now i tried to deploy my app(phone) in my **android** device, using below command.

```
ionic cordova run android
```

I am getting this error:

[image]

But the app runs fine in the **browser**.

I am unable to perceive the **error**.

Comment: Did you intstall cordova? npm install -g cordova

Comment: What do you get if you run cordova -v in the command prompt?

Comment: My cordova version is `9.0.0`

Comment: You should also run with the --verbose flag to get more information on why the process might be failing

Comment: The problem states that it's a dependency issue, you will have to check that you have to correct version of all the dependencies required by the Cordova plugin

Comment: hi SGR, is your problem solved?

Comment: This issue was solved, but after that got one more issue **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56388526/firebase-phone-authentication-in-ionic-4**

Comment: Hi, not able to download plugin >  ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase#GH-1057-April-05-android-build-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do try to remove and add again the *Android* platform

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
 ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-firebase



 ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase#GH-1057-April-05-android-build-issue
```

and see this link

[Ionic build issue -firebase](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/android-build-falid-the-library-com-google-android-gms-play-services-measurement-base-is-being-requested-by-various-other-libraries/163390/3)

Comment: When I run first command it got error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Mohit\testapp - Copy\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml'

Comment: When run second command got error > Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase#GH-1057-April-05-android-build-issue via registry.