# Ionic 4 Build Issue when add cordova-firebase plugin

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugins, ionic4

When I create basic IONIC 4 application and run > ionic cordova build android 
it works fine and apk generated.
When I add plugin firebase > ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase
It failed to build application.

ERROR:

> \platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':app:preDebugBuild' property 'compileManifests' during up-to-date check.
>     The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.5.0,16.5.0], [16.4.0,16.4.0]], but resolves to 16.5.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56373513/10127727